# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation

Tags: java, android, audio, equalizer, audioeffect

Right my app reports this crash every single day and it's resulting in a lot of uninstallers, which i don't like, now I've looked everywhere and all i know is that it's a very wide spread problem and it could also be a problem on Google's side but i just haven't been able to get real answers or solutions! so this is pretty much my last chance because like i said, it happens every single day!

Here's the LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simplistic.floating_equalizer/com.simplistic.floating_equalizer.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.checkStatus(AudioEffect.java:1244)
at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.setBandLevel(Equalizer.java:230)
at com.simplistic.floating_equalizer.model.EqualizerApi.setBandLevel(EqualizerApi.java:122)
at com.simplistic.floating_equalizer.model.Profile.loadSettings(Profile.java:125)
at com.simplistic.floating_equalizer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:160)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
... 11 more
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank's

Comment: Could you post the code as well? Thanks

Comment: I have similar error when my equalizer is running, then another equalizer app is opened and do some band level changes, then in my app I try to set band level it crashes. I think I'm not handling properly the onControlStatusChanges (and probably so are you:)

Comment: Guys, did you find any solution on this?

Comment: getting same error when i use mEqualizer.usePreset((short)0); If any1 has a ny soln, please post here...

Comment: Anyone has an answer for that?

Comment: just create a new Euaqlizer